# Prevent iframe from adding browser history

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, browser-history, ngroute

I have an angularjs app running within a third party iframe (i.e. different domains). All the routing and navigation within this app will add entries to the browser history, but I'd like to disable this app from do so. After much research, it seems that making use of the html5 history api is my best chance at this.

This reference makes use of a solution which essentially, onclick of a link within an iframe, will replace the current history state (history.replaceState()) with that of the links destination url. Thus the browser will not add a history entry if the current url is the same as the destination: http://www.webdeveasy.com/back-button-behavior-on-a-page-with-an-iframe/

I'm trying to implement a similar solution within an angular context which uses the ngRoute module for all navigation. With that said, I think adding a handler for the `$routeChangeStart` event is one solution, but it doesn't work:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(e, cur, pre) {     
    history.replaceState(null, null, $location.absUrl());       
});
```

In the above, this event handler appears to execute prior to navigation taking place. The `absUrl` is a path within the iframe app, and is the destination of the route, however the browser is still adding entries. Any ideas why?

---

**EDIT:**
So I found a partial solution. Much of the app navigates using `$location.path(myPath)`. If I add `replace()` onto the `$location.path()` then this tells the browser to replace the history entry instead of adding a new one.

This seems to work for all navigation which makes use of $location.path(), but not for user driven navigation (i.e. clicking links); I need to find a solution for those scenarios.